# How to combine multiple "Person" structured data in one HTML page?

Tags: html, json-ld

Is it possible to add more than one `Person` structured data in one page?

I have a website that shows search results for individuals' profiles, hence I want to know if it's possible to add structured data for each individual on the same search results page? As each structured data would point to a different URL to the profile's page.

When I tried this, Google's testing tool for strctured data was able to recognize only one strctured data which is the first, I tried the following:

```json
{ 
"@context": "http://schema.org/", 
"@type": "Person", 
"name": "Person1", 
"url": "Person1 url",
"image": "Person1 image", 
"jobTitle": "Person1 title", 
"worksFor": 
  { 
  "@type": "Organization", 
  "name": "Orgnization 1" 
  } 
}

{ 
"@context": "http://schema.org/", 
"@type": "Person", 
"name": "Person2", 
"url": "Person2 url",
"image": "Person2 image", 
"jobTitle": "Person2 title", 
"worksFor": 
  { 
  "@type": "Organization", 
  "name": "Orgnization 2" 
  } 
}
```

Is there something wrong with the code, do I have to add anything to combine them together or doesn't it work at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sample is not valid JSON-LD. You can't just list objects/entities after each other.

One solution is to place each entity into it's own `<script>` tag.

Another is to use the `@graph` concept as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30505796/json-ld-schema-org-multiple-video-image-page/30506476#30506476).

I personally prefer the separate `script` tags. If a script has syntax errors, the whole thing fails. With separate scripts, each is protect from any errors you may make in the others.

On to the idea itself. Google documents how it would like you to [mark up lists of things](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/mark-up-listings). In this case it's a summary page linking out to details pages. It may be best to follow Googles guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can [mix/combine structured data without any problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10421334/microdata-schema-org-how-to-mix-together-schemas).

In my experience, Google’s Structured Data Testing Tool fails from time to time, so I recommend to double check your code with [Linter](http://linter.structured-data.org/) or [this Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/structured-data-testing-t/kfdjeigpgagildmolfanniafmplnplpl).

In addition, you can wait and check [Google Structured Data Report in Google Search Console](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2650907?hl=en).