# Multiple products in an article - how to use structured data

Tags: seo, google-search, schema.org, microdata

I have an article containing several products. Let's say 'Bulb page' with 'White bulb' as a product, 'Yellow bulb' as another product and so on.

It seems that the product schema must be used when a web page has one product only.
Shouldn't I mark the products as 'product' to enhance seo and crawling?

Comment: See also: [How to combine multiple “Person” structured data in one HTML page?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/116526/how-to-combine-multiple-person-structured-data-in-one-html-page)

Comment: @StephenOstermiller 
Google writes: "List format is currently supported for the following content types: Recipe, Course, Article, Restaurant, Movie." Is it still ok?

Answer (score 1):

Its absolutely fine to markup multiple products on a single page. Use Google's [Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool) to see if your schema markup validates.